# MySQL: Optimize newsletter table columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables to mainain our newsletter subscriptions.

- 1st column stores user data, with unieque IDs for each.
- 2nd colum stores newsletter lists (i.e. user can subscribe to "Core
  updates" and/or "Tips and tricks"):

### id | name | description

- 3rd table store coloration between user and lists

### id | userId | listId | active

Let's assume that there are 5 lists available and user is subscribed to list number 1,3 and 5.

When he updates his newsletter preferences to 1,2 and 4 (only). I receive request with userId and new set of list ids [1,2,4]. With use of "active" column, I can perform action in 2 steps:

1. Disable all coleration (set active = 0 where userId = $id)
2. Activate only new ones (set active = 0 where userId = %id and listId IN (2,4)

I have following questions:

1. Is there a beter way than using active flag? I assume that without it I would have to fetch old configuration, compare with new and update records 1 by 1 which is less efficient.
2. How to handle new list on update. In our case, there were 5 correlations already, if meanwhile someone added 6th list was added and user want to subscribe to new list my update query will not affect 6th record so he will not be subscribed. I guess I could UPSERT but this isn't available in MySQL...
3. In case of unsubscribe, is it better to remove old records (1,3,5) and every time add new (2,4) or to keep it in DB and change status (looking from long term performance DB perspective taking into disk fragmentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a unique index on the combination user_id and list_id and insert every time a user updates his list. The duplicate insert query's will fail. So when the user is already subscribed to the list he will not subscribe again.

This however means the active column has to go and you cannot keep a history in the same table.

Comment: OK, what about unsubscribe? Remove entry?